# Execute a recurring job in Hangfire every 8 days

Tags: c#, cron, hangfire

Is it possible to create a recurring job in Hangfire that executes after a given number of days, say 8.

The nearest I found was to execute a job once in a week -

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("MyJob",() => ScheduledJob(), Cron.Weekly());
```

Understanding that Hangfire also accepts standard `CronExpression`, I've tried exploring cron expression for this frequency but couldn't found one for it-
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

One ugly solution could be to create 3 or 4 jobs that executes once in month at some dates accordingly, but I don't want to do that.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Finally I have used `CronExpression` like this to schedule a recurring job with frequency of every 8 days or for any number of days for that matter.

```
string cronExp = "* * */8 * *";
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("MyJob",() => ScheduledJob(), cronExp);
```

The third segment in `CronExpression` represents day of month.

The respective segments are as follows - (Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

[image]

Comment: I am in a similar situation. I am trying to execute a method at 23:58 everyday. The method seems to be running but it is running multiple times at 23:58.
Following the code. I don't whats going on. Thanks for your insights.

     RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => new DailyStatistics().Send(), Cron.Daily(3,58));

Comment: actually this have to be `0 * */8 * *` instead of `* * */8 * *` In your case it will run on each minute of each 8th day.

Comment: This is completely wrong! this will not run on every 8 day intervals, it will run on at every minute on every 8th day-of-month lol

Answer (score 15):

A more cleaner Solution will be to use **Cron.DayInterval(interval)**.

For your case it will be

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("MyJob",() => ScheduledJob(), Cron.DayInterval(8));
```

Comment: Nice! I guess it is added in the newer versions of hangfire. +1

Comment: Now obsolete, will be removed in Version 2.0.0