# run a recurring background job using hangfire every 28Days

Tags: asp.net, hangfire

please does anyhow know how to set a recurring background job to run every 28 days.that is the job should run based on 28Days and not the 28Days of the month. this is my current implemntation.

```
   string CropExpression = "0 20 */28  * * ";
   RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => _chargesJob.ChargeCustomerAccountMonthly(account.Id),CropExpression);
```

This current implementation runs the job on the 28th of every month which is not ideal for my app. What i want to achieve is that 28days should be calculated based on the current datetime. 
    For example if Datetime.now =2018/3/15, the recurring job should start counting from this date and elapse into the next month till it reaches 28 days.

Comment: .... then have a counter... once it reaches 28 it resets.. that way it does not care what day it is.

Comment: @Seabizkit please can you show me a sample

Comment: @user2943374 what's the problem with this expression? That cron expression means `run every 28 days at 20:00`. It should already do what you ask. If you wanted to run on the 28th you should remove the slash, eg `0 20 28  * * `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a recurring job in Hangfire every 8 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168738/execute-a-recurring-job-in-hangfire-every-8-days)

Comment: @user2943374 how do you know that the expression doesn't work? If you started the job in February 2018 it would run on the same day in March 2018 since February had 28 days. Have you tried with a *different* interval, eg every 1 minute, 1 hour or 1 day?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a job with a delay of 28 days. Then, when this job executes, set *another* job with a delay of 28 days.

See http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-with-delay.html for more details.

But the basic idea is:

```
public void Schedule()
{
    BackgroundJob.Schedule(
        () => {
           DoYourActualWork();
           Schedule();
        },
    TimeSpan.FromDays(28));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Charge customer monthly", 
    () => _chargesJob.ChargeCustomerAccountMonthly(account.Id), 
    Cron.DayInterval(28));
```

Comment: Somehting tells me that `Cron.DayInterval(28)` will produce `*/28` too. That *is* the correct syntaxt for recurring intervals

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the output was the same. what i want to achieve is if for example Datetime.now =march 20th 2018. 28Days should start counting from that date and not the 28th day of the month.

Comment: @user2943374 and the correct syntax for this is to use `*/28`, exactly what you used. How do you know that Hangfire *doesn't* work as it should? Remember that February 2018 had 28 days. If you started the job in February 2018 it would run on the same day in March 2018

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos because when i checked the next execution date of the job in hangfire, it will fire on the 28th of the same month